# Can this scenario lead to a race condition?

Tags: race-condition

Suppose that we have a message passing system using mailboxes. When sending to a full mail box or trying to receive from an empty one, a process does not block, instead, it gets an error code back. The process responds to the error code by just trying again, over and over, until it succeeds. Does this lead to race condition?

Comment: Looping without a delay, waiting for some event to occur (such as there being a message in a mailbox), is called "busy wait". It is not a race condition, but it is still undesirable.

Answer (score 0):

First at all I recommend to review what a [race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) means.

If the mailbox system handles "atomicity" when receiving/retrieving emails, there is no race condition. Your app may loop forever trying to retrieve a message but it isn't a race condition.

Now, let's imagine that the mailbox system does not use any kind of locking mechanism. If at the same time, you are trying to read if a new message exists, a new message is arriving to the mailbox, you may read an uncompleted message because is still reaching.

In the best case you get the uncompleted message but usually a crash occurs because of an invalid pointer, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The situation you describe wouldn't in itself lead to a race, though the actions you take in response to the error could, e.g pushing a "detected this mail box is empty" message to the empty mail box. Do that from two threads, you could easily end up with two mails.